# Flux interval stops execution when error occurs

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I'm using `Flux.interval` for running scheduled tasks

```
 Flux
        .interval(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .doOnNext(duration -> log.info("Process has been started"))
        .flatMap(duration -> customService.process())
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> Flux.empty())
        .subscribe();
```

The thing here that if an exception occurs in any place, `onErrorResume` has been called, but scheduler stops working - it doesn't call `customService.process()` anymore

I need this to continue calling method every 30 seconds even if there're any errors in any place. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: an exception is reactive is a `Terminal Event`

Answer (score 3):

In your case `.onErrorResume(throwable -> Flux.empty())` would just complete the flow without error signal but the original `Flux` will be canceled.

You have several options:

**Handle error in place**

Handle error on the `process` level. In this case error will be "ignored" and initial `Flux` will continue. Technically this is the same as wrapping `process` method in `try-catch` and ignore error in imperative programming.

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .doOnNext(i -> log.info("Process has been started: {}", i))
    .flatMap(i ->
            process(i)
                    .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage()))
                    .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
    );
```

```
Process has been started: 0
Process has been started: 1
Process has been started: 2
Process has been started: 3
Error: oops 3
Process has been started: 4
Process has been started: 5
Process has been started: 6
Process has been started: 7
```

**Retry**

You can use `.retry()` operator at the end of the sequence to retry any error or use `.retryWhen` if you need more granular control.

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .doOnNext(i -> log.info("Process has been started: {}", i))
        .flatMap(i ->
                process(i)
        )
        .retry();
```

Note that in this case every error will trigger re-subscription to the `Flux.interval` and the sequence will start over.

```
Process has been started: 0
Process has been started: 1
Process has been started: 2
Process has been started: 3
Error: oops 3
Process has been started: 0
Process has been started: 1
Process has been started: 2
Process has been started: 3
```