# FlatMapDelayError Inconsistent Error Propagation

Tags: project-reactor

Specifically this deals with how the upstream subscription is cancelled when an error occurs in the mapping operation.

From my testing it appears that thrown errors cancel the upstream subscription, where as propagated errors like those produced by Flux.error do not cancel the upstream subscription. When the upstream subscription is never cancelled the error is never propagated downstream and any error handlers are never triggered either, additionally no termination signal is propagated and results in a hanging flux.

I would think that a thrown error and a propagated error would be handled identically.

Is there a fundamental issue or concern I am not aware of when handling propagated errors from flatMapDelayError?

Below is also a simple example illustrating the problem on release train 2022.0.2. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
        Flux<Object> thrownFlux = Flux.just(0, 1, 2, 3).log()
                                      .flatMapDelayError(integer -> {
                                          throw new RuntimeException(); // Cancels upstream subscription
                                      }, 1, 1);

        // Completes as expected
        StepVerifier.create(thrownFlux)
                    .expectError()
                    .verify();

        Flux<Object> propagatedFlux = Flux.just(0, 1, 2, 3).log()
                                      .flatMapDelayError(integer -> {
                                          return Flux.error(new RuntimeException()); // Does not cancel upstream subscription
                                      }, 1, 1);

        // Never completes
        StepVerifier.create(propagatedFlux)
                .expectError()
                .verify();
```

Comment: I admit that there is something strange with the behaviour of *flatMapDelayError*. Maybe you should open an issue on reactor project directly. Note that, if you chain it with *onErrorContinue*, the error gets "swallowed", and then both flows ends empty. Now, *I think* that this behavior you see *might* be wanted, but the function doc is not very clear on how things work or should be handled then.

Comment: That is and interesting point with onErrorContinue it seems like it's interaction with the delay error and the underlying error strategy allows the flux to eventually complete. Although even the docs do not recommend the usage of onErrorContinue.
From looking at the source of flatMap it appeared the lack of cancellation may be intentional but I just can't find any reason why the flux would never complete either.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `reactor-core` possibly related to internal optimization. Downstream never requests next element after the error. All tests in reactor use `.hide()` to disable optimization https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/main/reactor-core/src/test/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxFlatMapTest.java#L604 and test works as expected. Probably you could use `hide()` as a temporary workaround and report the issue to  `reactor-core`.

Comment: Ah that is a good catch. I think you are right and this should be enough fuel for me to make an issue.

Comment: Although I noticed that while `.hide()` will at least allow the flux to complete it still doesn't cancel the upstream in the same way as the thrown error and consumes all the elements which could be problematic for hot infinite publishers.

Comment: Right, behavior is strange. Btw, what is your use case for using `flatMapDelayError`? probably it could be covered by using other operators.

Comment: I had been investigating using flatmapdelayerror to ensure that all messages in a hot flux are processed before an error is propagated due to an unexpected error like a mis-formatted message. 

I had used Flux.create to adapt to a provider provided listener framework and am using r2dbc to save data to a database. Everything right now is defensively using onErrorResume on downstream publishers. But was looking at flatMapDelayError to ensure an unexpected error didn't cause a malformed message to cause valid messages after it to get dropped since the flux would stop processing the backlog.

Comment: Not sure `flatMapDelayError` is a good solution for it.  I would suggest to handle errors while processing and skip . Here are some details https://stackoverflow.com/a/75166398/9068895

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I already do have the onErrorResume on the inner publisher as well as resubscription logic. So the flatmapdelayerror was mostly about ensuring no messages were dropped in case of an error outside the inner publisher.  As I didn't want to necessarily wrap all the message mapping logic into a flux just to use onErrorResume but that ultimately may be the safest way.

Comment: This turned out to be a bug in reactor and a fix was recently merged as seen here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/3353